# mediaElement TransportControls dimensions?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to overlay an InkCanvas over my MediaElement so that I can use my touchscreen to draw over video (similar to NFL coverage).

Here's the relevant XAML in my UWP project

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <MediaElement x:Name="mediaPlayer" AutoPlay="False" Source="Videos/collector_test.mp4" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" CurrentStateChanged="mediaPlayer_CurrentStateChanged"/>
                <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas"/>
            </Grid>
```

However, the `inkCanvas` covers the MediaTransportControls of `mediaPlayer`.  Is there a way to have `inkCanvas` only be the size of the video loaded as the source in the `mediaPlayer`?

Comment: Those controls are other xaml elements. Maybe you can recreate them on top of the ink canvas and bind them to the media element

Comment: After some more investigation, i found that the `mediaTransportControls` are 120px tall, so I set my `inkCanvas` to be top aligned with a bottom margin of 120 to achieve what i wanted.

Comment: Is this going to work on all screen sizes?